# How does one perform Salah on a plane?

Tags: salat, travelling

Suppose you have two days worth of travelling with very little time to perform Salah with connecting flights.  How does one perform Salah on a plane?  Bearing in mind the following:

- you cannot get out of your seat and start Salah in the aisle because people are going up and down the aisle;
- you may hit turbulence and must sit in the seat with seatbelts fastened;
- the aisle may not be clean due to people walking through it with dirty shoes, food crumbs; etc.

Also, what if you are travelling where the timezone is actually going behind in hours from your origin of travel? (E.g. the UK to the USA and there is a time difference of maybe 5, 6 or even 8 hours)? It would appear that for example the time Zuhr would always be given the position of the sun etc.

Please also remember, I am asking for authentic sources (Sunni school of thought also) and how to pray whilst in travel but also what "timezone" to follow when travelling.

Comment: Maybe relevant [What should be done regarding Salat on a long flight?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14475/praying-on-an-extended-flight)

Comment: I think your exaggerating with the timezone matter. Because even if the airplane is very fast you would in best case arrive at a prayer timing which is more or less the same as the one you started at (assuming you are crossing time zones) and the prayer time has a lower and an upper bound so all you can do is pray between both or if you joined prayers at the ending time for the earlier prayer or the beginning of the later prayer. But if one of them entered while you are resident you can't pray it qassr (shortened).

Comment: thank you @Medi1Saif - trust me, I am not exaggerating at all. This is an actual fact. i.e you leave the UK say, 1pm which is roughly the time for Zuhr. Then you arrive at your destination say, 8pm local time. At this point you have missed Asr and maybe Mughrib. But from the origin of leaving, you have actually missed Asr, Mugrib AND Isha because of the timezone difference.

Comment: I think you are too quick and keen to close/duplicate topic. Please be respectful and relax, let the OP (me) clarify things. The timezone IS a problem as I have been clearly saying in the post!!!! you arrive EARLIER than when you left

Comment: I think you are complicating things, yes the hanafi madhab here is creating difficulties where there shouldn't be as it contradicts sahih hadiths but the matter is simple: Pray joined and shortened prayers take a stone with you and perform taymum, pray while sitting. The qiblah doesn't matter, as you are like a rider of a horse or camel not able to guid it while praying. Once you've settled down somewhere you even could re-do the prayers.

Comment: Of course it is more difficult if you may have to sit an airplane while more than two prayer times are passing, as then you might have to plan your travel and try to calculate or check the approximate timings for prayers, for this you may need information like the route of the airplane, etc. or just have a good look at the sky to find out an approximate time! But in practice it is easy to some extent: When it begins to become dark outside you can pray maghrib and 'isha', before that dohr and 'asr ...

Comment: If this is the kind of answer you'd like to have i can try to formulate one and back it up with references as good as i can. But I'm quite not sure whether time zones really play a role for the prayer timings. As one mostly doesn't correct his watch in each zone!

Comment: if you arrive earlier you flight to west. time diff is substracted. you need to substract 1 hour of pm then 12 hours of am then 4 hours of pm to get 8pm that is earlier. so it is uk-17 hours, it is utc-17, there is such thing. maximums are -12 and +12 utc.

Comment: as far as i know sunni mazhabs are like "dead", or frozen, i do not know about shii mazhab. if you know this, why you expect they have regulations for time zones? they could not go so quickly in that times.