# Praying during a flight: Which way of purification is correct?

Tags: practical-islam, wudu, tayammum

I think my question is somewhat related to:[What should be done regarding Salat on a long flight?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14475/what-should-be-done-regarding-salat-on-a-long-flight)

However I'd like to know what is the most correct choice for the purification during a flight (if one for example would miss a prayer if he/she wouldn't pray in the aircraft):

Could we say tayamum is valid or would it need wudu'?

I mean in the aircraft of course there are toilets with water, but isn't it an abuse to use this water for wudu' and therefore one could do tayamum or is wudu' necessary because water is available?

Comment: why should it be abuse? do you use much of water for wudu? as i know you should not use too much of water for wudu. using too much water is israf.

Comment: @qdinar the water tanks in an airplane have a limited volume, and planes have lots of passengers, so depending on the length if a flight using this water for such thing as ablution can clearly be considered as abuse! For wudu' you'll need several litres of water (in best case ~2l)

Comment: @Medi1Saif: I only use 1 litre. And wudu isn't abuse of water. It's something you need to make your salat valid. Besides the average volume of a water tank of an airplane of average size is 700 litres depending on the amount of passengers on board.

Comment: @Tarik hm... have you calculated how much water runs when you use the toilet etc.

Comment: It's like 10 litres but that's in a house. In an airplane they used much less water. Some even use suction pressure instead of water.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salamu 'aleykum

Of course you need to perform wudu. The amount of water that's available during a flight of an average plane is on average 700 litres.
So 1-2 litres doesn't matter for let's say the longest flight you can take on this planet is 24 hours.

It's like 5-10 litres of water you use and the pdf-document I provided also shows the average use of water from passengers per hour which comes down to 0.4 Litres.
And not every passenger on the plane is Muslim. If it was so and every muslim performed wudu on that plane during that 24 hour flight which isn't very probable then it would become a problem. But this is an extreme case scenario.

So just perform your wudu if you're physically able to do so.

Rest assured with the help of Allah (swt)

Source:

http://www.win.tue.nl/~rhofstad/KLM_paperNewVersion.pdf

Comment: See the pdf for more info. You will get on average the consumption of water from passengers every 1hour for the Royal Dutch Airline KLM.

Comment: @Medi1Saif: It's just in case they forget to do so which happens very often.

Comment: Can you post any evidence to support your claim?

Comment: Didn't you see the pdf-document? Why are you downvoting all my answers?

Comment: I guess the claim he means is: "Of course you need to perform wudu. "

Comment: None has down-voted this!